# Log Output in DBUnit

Tags: dbunit

I feel that this is something I could easily figure out but I'm having a hard time finding information on how to change the log level of DBUnit.  Can anyone solve this problem for me?

Comment: DBUnit uses SLF4J to handle logging.  So the logging for DBUnit is controlled but the underlined logger.  Thanks to John Hurst from the DBUnit group for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After avoiding the problem for a while, I came to a solution.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;


Logger logger = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.dbunit")
logger.setLevel(Level. ERROR);
```

Hopefully this lead someone to a solution to their own similar problem.

Comment: The "org.slf4j.Logger" import should be removed from this answer, because the Logger in the last two lines is of type ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger, and not org.slf4j.Logger. Also, there are missing semicolons.

Answer (score 7):

When using log4j add the following to your `log4j.properties`:

```
# DbUnit
log4j.logger.org.dbunit=ERROR
```

Comment: I was looking for a more programmatic approach but this would be good as well.

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot, you may simply add the following property to your `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.dbunit: ERROR
```