# Glassfish is spammed with logging

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am using DBUnit and I wonder how I can stop Glassfish from logging all the things that happen with it. It seems like both an info level log and debug level log is printed at once. Why so, and how is it possible to set dbunit to WARN

> [#|2012-11-09T20:43:08.579+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|20:43:08.579
>   [http-thread-pool-8080(1)] DEBUG org.dbunit.util.xml.XmlWriter -
>   close() - start

Answer (score 1):

The log level is not controlled by Glassfish, but by DBUnit. See the related question: [Log Output in DBUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980630/log-output-in-dbunit).